# How can I connect my bot to different channels?

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I have created a Microsoft Bot, a C# and Web API application. Added Intent in Luis, able to do unit test using Bot Framework Simulator. I want to connect this bot to various channels like Skype for Business, Skype etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign up and register your bot here: https://dev.botframework.com/bots. Once you have registered your bot, you can do the following to connect your bot to a channel:

1. Click **My bots**.
2. Select the bot that you want to configure.
3. Click the **Channels** tab.
4. Under **Add channel** on the bot dashboard, click the channel to add.

You can choose from a variety of channels including Slack, Teams, Bing etc.

- [Detailed steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/Skype-For-Business-Bot-Framework/docs/overview) on registering a bot for **Skype for Business**.
- [Detailed steps](https://dev.skype.com/bots) for **Skype bots**.

Hope this helps!